# Exponentially increasing number towards maximum

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I'm trying to build a retry mechanism for sending e-mails. I'd like it to be configurable so that administrators can specify both;

- The number of retries (intervals)
- The maximum number of seconds before giving up

A further requirement is that the number of seconds to wait between each retry increases exponentially (or follows some other geometric sequence) up to the maximum.

Another way of describing the problem is: **How can the maximum number of seconds be divided up into X number of intervals where each interval is exponentially larger than its predecessor?**

I'm not sure if this can be expressed using a purely mathematical representation, if not examples in C# would be welcomed. However, I'm really just looking for the logic here so provided the it's well explained I'm sure any language could be easily translated.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that instead of simply doubling the wait value after each retry, checking whether you exceed the maximum? Anyway, geometric sequences are pretty basic, it's faster to google it if you don't remember

Comment: It doesn't sound as though its doubling, more like a positive exponential curve. Red Taz, have you tried/researched anything yet?

Comment: @Sayse Doubling is exponential with a power of 2. If the OP wants a different power, he can just use Math.Pow. In any case, 1) what's the point of precalculating all the intervals 2) That's simply solving the geometric sequence.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - True, but doubling is very specific and it sounds like the op may want something more variant

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're re-framing the question by eliminating the configurable number of intervals

Comment: @RedTaz no - I'm asking two things: 1) why don't you use a simple loop 2) if you have to precalculate, sequences are high-school math. Have you tried solving this? Why shouldn't this question be considered off-topic?

Comment: 1) a simple loop does not provide the level of configuration required. 2) the sequence cannot be pre-calculated if both the maximum and the number of intervals are both variable, wouldn't you agree? 3) the question is on topic because it is programming related and aims to address a real-world problem.

Comment: Where is the problem ? Lets say the administrator put 5 retries and interval is 10 sec. What is bothering you ? What are the expected answers ? Also I will not going to make exact retry mechanism in this case, because you are going to lose valuable information! The information is why this email is not sent on first time !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some math : Lets have variable `T` (total time), `N` (number of retries), `t` (time of first try) and `e` (exponent). Each try would take: `t*1` , `t*e`, `t*e*e`, `t*e*e*e`, etc..

So total time can be written as `T = t*e^0 + t*e^1 + t*e^2 +.. + t*e^N` rewritten : `T = t*(e^0+e^1+e^2 .. + e^N)`. We can calculate the [sum of powers](http://mikestoolbox.com/powersum.html) as : `sum = (e^N-1)/(e-1)` .

So given `T`, `N` and `e`, we can calculate `t` as : `t = T/((e^N-1)/(e-1))`

To calculate time for `i`th iteration use : `ti = t*e^i`

For example, given T = 124(s), N = 5(tries) and e = 2, the first interval will be `124/((2^5-1)/(2-1)) = 4s` . The following intervals will then be :

- 0th interval: 4s (t*e^0)
- 1st interval: 4*2 = 8s (t*e^1)
- 2nd interval: 8*2 = 4*2*2 = 16s (t*e^2)
- 3rd interval: 16*2 = 4*2*2*2 = 32s (t*e^3)
- 4nd interval: 32*2 = 4*2*2*2*2 = 64s (t*e^4)

For total time of 124s of waiting.

Sorry for the formatting. This question would probably be better for [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

The code to calculate all intervals would be :

```
public static void TestFunction(int max, int numIntervals) {

    List<double> intervals = new List<double>();

    double exponent = 2;

    double n = Math.Pow(exponent, numIntervals) - 1;
    double d = exponent - 1;

    double t = max / (n / d);

    for (int x = 0; x < numIntervals; x++) {
        double interval = t * Math.Pow(exponent, x);
        intervals.Add(interval);
    }

}
```

Comment: this looks promising but in the question we would be given `T` and `N`. Therefore `e` would need to be derived somehow. That's what I'm struggling with.

Comment: @RedTaz That is not possible. You cannot use one one equation and two unknowns. e should either be a parameter or it can be hard-coded. For example using e=2 will make each try take 2x longer than before.

Comment: @RedTaz No. There is no iteration number. e is how fast the interval is growing.

Comment: @RedTaz No. See my edit. Also, this is high-school math.

Comment: @RedTaz I don't know what math you are using, but this is geometrical, not linear.

Comment: You can include images with formulas if you think this too ugly. I tend to take them off wikipedia or use an online latex editor.

Comment: Sorry for causing more confusion than was necessary (mostly my confusion!), this precisely answers the question

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how useful this answer is but it was certainly fun to create. What makes this answer somewhat different is that it computes the base used for the exponential computation of the time intervals.

So the input is a total time as well as a number of intervals to divide this time span into. The length of the first interval is specified and the challenge is to compute the remaining intervals to ensure that they increase exponentially and sum to the total time.

This can be formulated as a mathematical equation:

*t∙x*<sup>0</sup> + *t∙x*<sup>1</sup> + ... + *t∙x<sup>n</sup>* = *T*

*t* is the length of the first interval and *T* is the total time. *n* is the number of intervals and *x* is the unknown base.

Assuming that *x* is not 1 then this equation can be rewritten into a standard form for a polynomial equation:

*x<sup>n</sup>* - *r∙x* + *r* - 1 = 0

where *r = T/t* is the ratio between the total time and the length of the first interval.

As far as I know this equation has no general solution but it can be solved using an algorithm in a numerical analysis library. I chose a Newton-Raphson algorithm from the [Math.Net Numerics](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) library available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics/). For this algorithm the first derivative of the polynomium is required and this is

*n∙x*<sup>*n* - 1</sup> - *r*

Putting it all together to create a sequence of exponentially growing time spans to wait:

```
IEnumerable<TimeSpan> ExponentialTimeSpans(TimeSpan firstTimeSpan, TimeSpan totalTimeSpan, Int32 count) {
  var ratio = totalTimeSpan.TotalSeconds/firstTimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
  var @base = RobustNewtonRaphson.FindRoot(
    x => Math.Pow(x, count) - ratio*x + ratio - 1,
    x => count*Math.Pow(x, count - 1) - ratio,
    1d + 1E-8, // Assume that base is > 1
    100d // Arbitrary (but BIG) upper limit on base
  );
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i += 1)
    yield return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(firstTimeSpan.TotalSeconds*Math.Pow(@base, i));
}
```

Note that you easily can provide input with no solutions and that will result in an exception being thrown. However, any sensible input based on the original problem statement should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for expanding my horizons! I like this alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following maybe?

```
var time_in_seconds = 10000; // usually done in milliseconds, so lets say 10 sec.

// if email fails:
time_in_seconds *= 10; 
// So, next will be 100, 1000, etc. & you get your exponential increment.
```

Answer (score 0):

Step one - a simple solution - work in reverse!  (Where the reduction is 50%)

I need to fit 10 intervals into 128 seconds.

```
Interval :  Time (Of occurrence)
1        :  128
2        :  64
3        :  32
4        :  16
5        :  8
6        :  4
7        :  2
8        :  1
9        :  1/2
10       :  1/4
```

Note:  The above works fine (to keep under X, just start with X/2).  The below, not so much.  This techniques can be applies iteratively to find a 'good' solution though for now.

Great, but what happens if we need a minimum?  1/128th of a second between retries at the start may be unnecessary.   So what we need to do, is vary the exponential.

Now the above can be written as `result = 1/4 * 2^9` or more generally `result = startingInterval * 2^(n-1)`.  However we know the result we want, so we need to rearrange this formula.

`(result/startingInterval)^(1/(n-1)) =   base`

With the above values:
`(128/(1/4))^(1/(10-1)) =  base = 2`

Or in other words, to get a total time of 128s starting with an interval of 1/4s and using 10 attempts (including the first one) then we need to increase the length between intervals by a factor of 2 each attempt.

Comment: But 128 should be to total sum of all intervals, not the maximum interval.

Comment: Hmm, let me think it over.  I'll need time I don't have to think it over :P

Answer (score -1):

Declare a max threshold value as well an offset to be added for each retry.

```
int maxRetryCount = 5;
int offSet = 10000;
int currRetryCount = 0;
int waitTime = 1000; //default value

while(currRetryCount < maxRetryCount)
{
    try
    {
        //Send Email 
        // break out once the email is send
        break;
    }
    catch
    {
        //Wait for a while
        Thread.Sleep(waitTime);

        //increase the wait time for next time
        waitTime += offSet;
        currRetryCount++;
    }
}
```

Here the code will attempt for at most 5 times to send an email where the wait time will increase by 10 sec each time.

Comment: Will anybody plz explain why would you put a negative rank without explanation??

Comment: I'm not your down voter, and one of the best (and worst) things about voting is that it's anonymous. But I could speculate that the vote arose since you didn't answer the question. `How can the maximum number of seconds be divided up into X number of intervals where each interval is *exponentially larger* than its predecessor?` You didn't use any of the parameters that the OP wants to use.

Comment: Thanks @JamesWebster for the reply. While you're correct about anonymity, but I guess the ultimate objective is to get the correct ans. And if you don't point the mistakes how could you expect others to help. Besides this is just another way of achieving the same thing that OP has mentioned in his bullet points.

Comment: `if you don't point the mistakes how could you expect others to help`. Just the act of voting might get you to look at the question again.

Comment: Secondarily, you seem to have completely missed the concept of a `maximum time` in your answer